# If vs Case. If incrementing strangely

Tags: c, embedded

I'm learning embedded programming, and have a LED board and button board hooked up to the same PORT.

The commented out if statement under the chk_button function, certain buttons when activated will add to the num variable its intended increment + 1. IE: pushing button 1 will increment num by three. The current case statement works to spec.

I understand case statements when compiled effectively become look up tables, and thus have smaller footprint and run faster,but I am uncertain as to WHY im getting the bug that I am.

I'm also open to any other criticisms in my code.

```
//  HARDWARE SETUP:
//  PORTA is connected to the segments of the LED display. and to the pushbuttons.
//  PORTA.0 corresponds to segment a, PORTA.1 corresponds to segement b, etc.
//  PORTB bits 4-6 go to a,b,c inputs of the 74HC138.
//  PORTB bit 7 goes to the PWM transistor base.

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define F_CPU 16000000
#define DIGIT_ONE  0x00
#define DIGIT_TWO  0x10
#define DIGIT_COLON 0x20
#define DIGIT_THREE  0x30
#define DIGIT_FOUR 0x40

//******************************************************************************
//                           debounce_switches
//Checks the state of the button number passed to it. It shifts in ones till
//the button is pushed. Function returns a 1 only once per debounced button
//push so a debounce and toggle function can be implemented at the same time.
//Adapted to check all buttons from Ganssel's "Guide to Debouncing"
//Expects active low pushbuttons on PINA port.  Debounce time is determined by
//external loop delay times 12.
//Saves status of button (i) into a state array.
//******************************************************************************
int8_t debounce_switches(uint16_t *state, uint8_t i) {
  state[i] = (state[i] << 1) | (! bit_is_clear(PINA, i)) | 0xE000;
  if (state[i] == 0xF000) return 1;
  return 0;
}
//******************************************************************************
//                          chk_buttons
//Checks the buttons. Calls debounce_switches in a loop passing both the state array
//and the current switch being checked.
//If debounce_switches returns a 1 for a switch, case statements determine which switch
//was activated, and increments count by the appropriate value.
//******************************************************************************
void chk_buttons(uint16_t *state, uint16_t *num)
{
    uint8_t itr;
    for( itr=0; itr<8; itr++)
    {
        if( debounce_switches(state, itr))
        {
            switch(itr)
            {
                case 0:
                    *num += 1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    *num += 2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    *num += 4;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    *num += 8;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    *num += 16;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    *num += 32;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    *num += 64;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    *num +=128;
                    break;
            }
        /*
            if (itr == 0)     *num += 1;
            else if(itr == 1) *num += 2;
            else if(itr == 2) *num += 4;
            else if(itr == 3) *num += 8;
            else if(itr == 4) *num += 16;
            else if(itr == 5) *num += 32;
            else if(itr == 6) *num += 64;
            else if(itr == 7) *num += 128;
        */
        }


    }
}

//******************************************************************************
//                         itoseven
// Accepts a number from 0 -9 Returns a hex value to display on the seven segment..
//******************************************************************************
uint8_t itoseven(uint8_t num)
{
    uint8_t segnum;
    switch(num)
    {
        case 0:
                 segnum = ~0x3F;
                 return segnum;
        case 1:
               segnum = ~0x06;
               return segnum;
        case 2:
               segnum = ~0x5B;
               return segnum;
        case 3:
               segnum = ~0x4F;
               return segnum;
        case 4:
               segnum = ~0x66;
               return segnum;
        case 5:
               segnum = ~0x6D;
               return segnum;
        case 6:
               segnum = ~0x7D;
               return segnum;
        case 7:
               segnum = ~0x07;
               return segnum;
        case 8:
               segnum = ~0x7F;
               return segnum;
        case 9:
             segnum = ~0x6F;
             return segnum;
    }
}

//***********************************************************************************
//                                   segment_sum
//takes a 16-bit binary input value and displays the result to the LED board.
//***********************************************************************************
void segsum(uint16_t num) {
    uint8_t ones;
    uint8_t tens;
    uint8_t hundreds;
    uint8_t thousands;
  //break up decimal sum into 4 digit-segments
    ones = num % 10;
    tens = (num/10)%10;
    hundreds = (num/100)%10;
    thousands = (num/1000)%10;
  //determine how many digits there are
    if(num < 10)
    {
        PORTB = DIGIT_ONE;
        PORTA = itoseven(num);
    }
    else if(num > 9 && num <100)
    {
        PORTB = DIGIT_ONE;
        PORTA = itoseven(ones);
        _delay_ms(2);
        PORTB = DIGIT_TWO;
        PORTA = itoseven(tens);
    }
    else if(num > 99 && num < 1000)
    {
        PORTB = DIGIT_ONE;
        PORTA = itoseven(ones);
        _delay_ms(2);
        PORTB = DIGIT_TWO;
        PORTA = itoseven(tens);
        _delay_ms(2);
        PORTB = DIGIT_THREE;
        PORTA = itoseven(hundreds);
    }
    else if (num >999)
    {
        PORTB = DIGIT_ONE;
        PORTA = itoseven(ones);
        _delay_ms(2);
        PORTB = DIGIT_TWO;
        PORTA = itoseven(tens);
        _delay_ms(2);
        PORTB = DIGIT_THREE;
        PORTA = itoseven(hundreds);
        _delay_ms(2);
        PORTB = DIGIT_FOUR;
        PORTA = itoseven(thousands);
    }
}

uint8_t main()
{
    DDRB = 0xF0; //set port bits 4-7 B as outputs
    uint16_t num = 0;
    uint16_t state[8];
    //initialize array values for debouncing
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        state[i]= 0;
    }
    while(1)
    {
        //make PORTA an input port with pullups
        DDRA = 0x00;
        PORTA = 0xFF;
        //enable tristate buffer for pushbutton switches
        PORTB = 0x70;
        //check the buttons. Increment by appropriate value if switch is active.
        chk_buttons(&state, &num);
        //rollover at 1023
        if(num > 1023)
            num = 1;
        //switch PORTA to output
        DDRA = 0xFF;
        //Send num to display
        segsum(num);
        _delay_ms(2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This *looks* like C (not sure about `uint8_t main()` though...). If you show code, you should *tag the language*. It helps people find the question and also helps the system to apply the correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: "behave strangely", exactly what error do you get? btw if you need a codereview there is a site for that. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @crashmstr: A freestanding environment may use any signature of `main` - actually even `main` is not required, but the function called at startup is implementation defined. However, it typically is `void main(void)` or some inpur argument(s), but no result. Most times `main` is `_Noreturn`, too.

Answer (score 1):

I've update these functions to remove the switches as they are not needed at all.  Note how the first uses an algorithm in place of a switch and the second uses a table that is easy to adjust in the future.  Also, assert/error check your inputs and you'll be a happier camper when things go sideways.

```
void chk_buttons(uint16_t *state, uint16_t *num)
{
    // Assert bad state and num here.  

    uint8_t itr;
    for( itr=0; itr<8; itr++)
    {
        if( debounce_switches(state, itr))
        {
            *num += 1 << itr; // Could also use |= as that is what we are doing.
        }
    }
}

uint8_t itoseven(uint8_t num)
{
    // assert num <= 9

    const uint8_t kLookup[10] = 
    {~0x3f, ~0x06, ~0x5B, ~0x4F, ~0x66, 
     ~0x6D, ~0x7D, ~0x07, ~0x7F, ~0x6F};

    return kLookup[num];
}
```

For the last function, if you start at the 4-digit number check and work backwards to the single digit, it becomes a very simple loop to do your complex digit calculation.  Just divide your mask from 10,000 to 10.  I'll post that code a bit later as I have time.

---

**Update**

Here is something I coded up that demonstrates the idea.  You will need to modify it for your own functions as right now it just outputs ASCII.  It fails for negative numbers (as does your code), but that is very easy to add with a simple if check / ABS / prepend a minus character.

```
int main(void)
{
    int num = 9876;

    // Starting at the 5th digit.  You could use 1000 instead if 
    // there were only 4 digits or less ever.
    int digitMask = 10000;
    char output[16];
    int index = 0;

    // Handle 0 case.
    if(num== 0)
    {
        output[index++] = '0';
    }
    else
    {
        // Skip leading 0's
        while((num / digitMask) == 0)
        {
            digitMask /= 10;
        }

        // While there may be digits to process...
        while(digitMask)
        {
            // Grab MS Digit and mod it away from total.
            int digit = num / digitMask;
            num %= digitMask;

            // Convert to ASCII (you would use your own function)
            output[index++] = digit + '0';

            // Update mask - note we could use a for/loop here just as easily.
            digitMask /= 10;
        }
    }

    // Terminate string and print it.
    output[index] = 0;
    printf("%s", output);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Holy cow. I didnt see any of that coming. This is amazing.

If I understand your suggestion correctly, I should work my way from Most significant to least significant in a loop. But I'm not sure what you mean by changing my mask from 10,000 to 10.

Comment: @OllieP He said "divide", not "change". I've only skimmed your code, but maybe a loop that starts at 10,000 and divides by 10 each step, down to 10?

Comment: Minor: Suggest `1u << itr`  (add u) to prevent the evils of UB with shifting into the sign bit.  OTOH does not make much diff even with `1 << 7`